# Best approach/pattern for showing large data from webservice in list view

Tags: android, web-services, design-patterns, listview

This goes longer, but I need to explain.

I have an application which requires to show data of thousands of items in a list view. This can be compared to Google Play Store which features large number of apps in particular category.
( Most of those apps use lazy loading which loads more and more data as user scrolls down. Another app is Gmail app conversations list. We keep scrolling to load more.
We can see same in Google Image Search Desktop Version. )

But above has a limit to which list items are populated, at the end it just stops to load more data. But what if it is a list of people names in alphabetical order. I cannot stop with few names listed. Also do not wish to have a alphabets choice load list.

What would be an ideal solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement **Paging** mechanism at server side so that you will be having particular number of records page by page, this way you will implement load more functionality same as Google play and other apps.

Comment: My question is how to show all items, some design, in case when every item is important. Not like few top items in Google Play Store, which stops scrolling down after a certain extent.

Comment: I mean with Pattern to display, I agree its not feasible to load a large list (along with connected data for each item click), that will cause out of memory.